# NASM - How can I solve the input reading problem from the terminal?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data
yourinputis db "your input is =",0
len equ $ - yourinputis

section .bss
msginput    resb    10

section .text
global _start


_start:
    mov eax,3 ;read syscall
    mov ebx,2
    mov ecx,msginput
    mov edx,9 ; I don't know that is correct?
    int 80h

    mov eax,4 ;write syscall
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,yourinputis
    mov edx,len
    int 80h

    mov eax,4 ;write syscall
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,msginput
    mov edx,10
    int 80h


exit:
    mov eax,1 ;exit syscall
    xor ebx,ebx
    int 80h
```

This code working very well. But It is so terrible bug(for me:(). If I enter an input longer than 10 --->

```
$./mycode
012345678rm mycode
your input is 012345678$rm mycode
$
```

This is happening. And of course "mycode" is not exist right now.

What should I do?

EDIT:The entered input is correctly printed on the screen. But if you enter a long input, it moves after the 9th character to the shell and runs it.

In the example, the "rm mycode" after "012345678" is running in the shell.

Comment: You should be reading from FD 0, not FD 2. 0 = stdin, 2 = stderr

Comment: I can't see any reason why it's printing more than 10 characters.

Comment: @Barmar nothing has changed

Comment: That's because by default they're all connected to `/dev/tty`, so it doesn't cause a problem. But it wouldn't work properly if you redirected input `./mycode <filename`

Comment: That comment wasn't intended as a solution to the problem, just pointing out an unrelated issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you enter more than 9 characters, they're left in the terminal driver's input buffer. When the program exits, the shell reads from the terminal and tries to execute the rest of the line as a command.

To prevent this, your program should keep reading in a loop until it gets a newline.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this on an example?

Comment: Hrrrrrrmmm… A sophisticated solution would do a `ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TCFLSH, TCIFLUSH)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the characters one by one until you reach `0x0a`. Something like:

```
_read:
    mov esi, msginput

_loop:
    mov eax,3 ;read syscall
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx, esi
    mov edx,1 ; I don't know that is correct?
    int 80h

    cmp byte[esi], 0x0a
    je end

    inc esi
    jmp _loop

end:
   ret
```

You would have to increase the size of `msginput` tho.

IMPORTANT: Do note that this is not the efficient way to do this (see the comments), it is only put here as an example to the answer above.

Comment: I am getting error:invalid combination of opcode and operands. For ```mov ecx,si```

Comment: @suiciyom oh yea sorry I forgot that it is 32 bit

Comment: You don't need to read 1 byte at a time.  With a TTY in "cooked" mode (the default), normally you won't get anything until the user hits return or EOF to submit the line-edit buffer.  So just use a large enough buffer, and/or keep reading until you find a character you're looking for, or until `read()` returns `0` (or error).  That will make your program work like `cat` or `wc` or other normal programs that consume all their stdin.

Comment: You only need to read 1 byte at a time if you specifically need to stop reading at the end of a line, and might be reading from a file or stream that has multiple lines ready for reading.  It's very inefficient to do it that way.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was only trying to give an example to the answer above or at least this was what I understood from that answer.

Comment: Ok, but I'm telling you it's not a good followup or addition.  The TTY normally *is* in cooked mode, and reading until you've consumed *all* the input is the normal thing.  Either stopping after one successful `read` (with a large buffer) for a toy program that wants to exit after one line, or reading until a `read` returns `0` is the usual EOF idiom.  Or read until a read returns short and/or ends with a newline.  Anyway, there is usually no need to avoid reading past a newline on stdin, and a larger `read` size will just return a lower number of characters read.

Comment: I mean you *could* do this, but it's not a *good* suggestion for beginners to learn from.  The problem here is all about understanding how Unix TTYs work.  Which is why I closed it as a duplicate of another asm question with some TTY details in answers.  I didn't go looking for other better duplicates, but there have been lots over the years, some using C instead of asm to make `read` calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok, thanks for the feedback, I will not delete the answer (should I?) so that OP can read your comments as well (if that is appropriate).

Comment: Yeah that's probably a reasonable choice.  You might want to edit a note into your answer that it's not en efficient or recommended way to do things, and to see comments, if you think that's appropriate.